# How Can I use parameter in OPENROWSET() function?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get an image from a shared folder, but while I am trying to pass parameter in `OPENROWSET` function I am getting an error:

> Incorrect Syntax near......

I tried this one so far:

```
alter FUNCTION dbo.GetImage (@imagePath varchar(200))
RETURNS varbinary(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varbinary(max);
    
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'net use Z: \\192.168.1.175\Rack /user:192......\username pass';
    
    SELECT @Result = ProjectImage
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'Z:' + @imagePath, SINGLE_BLOB) AS ProjectImage(ProjectImage);
    
    RETURN @Result;
END;
```

Comment: @DaleK I already tried, in that case i am getting the error is openrowset is expecting string or text_lex value

Comment: There is your answer then, it doesn't take a parameter. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), its a string constant i.e. not a parameter.

Comment: The only way around that would be to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. `OPENROWSET` only takes a string constant, so you need to use dynamic SQL to inject your file path to the SQL then execute that SQL. You will however not be able to do this within a function, so you're best bet is to use a stored procedure and an output parameter to get the varbinary out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetImage (@imagePath varchar(200), @Result VARBINARY(max) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'net use Z: \\192.168.1.175\Rack /user:192......\username pass';

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = 
                N'SELECT @Result = BulkColumn 
                FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''Z:' + @imagePath + N''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS t';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Result varbinary(max) OUTPUT', @Result OUTPUT;

    RETURN @Result;
END;
```

With that being said, if you're only looking to read a file and convert it to binary then SQL doesn't really feel like the right tool for the job - I'm never a big fan of conflating file system tasks with the database except for in ad hoc processes, but ad hoc processes should not require a permanent solution like a function or a stored procedure.

Comment: If I execute this function then i will be getting an error. which is exactly: Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Comment: Yes, thought that shortly after posting. You can't do this in a function, but could use a stored procedure. As I've just added in the edit though, this feels like something that is possibly better suited outside of SQL

Comment: I tried add credentials within openrowset function, but getting error.
'SELECT ProjectImage
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\192.168.1.175\Rack\Common\SwadeshLogo.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS ProjectImage(ProjectImage)
WITH (PROVIDER='SQLNCLI', 
      DATA SOURCE='\\192.168.1.175', 
      USER ID='user', 
      PASSWORD='pass');'
error is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: You've got an error because that is not valid syntax - I am not really sure what you are trying to do here, why would you pass SQL connection credentials to open an image file? The valid syntax is defined in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The more I hear about your problem, the more I think you are trying to force a square peg into a round hole by doing this in SQL Server. Consider another tool better suited for file system tasks

Comment: i need to show image in report builder. and images are in shared folder, to access that folder i need to give credentials. that is why i am trying to do it by using sql server.